# Where does the nick-name for Beethoven's Piano Sonata No. 14 in C-sharp Minor, Op. 27, No. 2 come from?

Tags: history

It is commonly said in music spheres that Beethoven did not give the Sonata the title of Moonlight. That leads me to wonder what is the source of the unofficial name then if not from the composer?

Comment: So a music critic the answer does not say which one. It does not really answer my question. I would like to know what person coined the phrase. I don't really care why it was called what it is, I want to know who called it by that name.

Comment: The answer might not say which one, but the highest-rated comment to the question does.

Comment: The other question is vaguely related, but the answer to *this* one is only contained in a comment therein. How would searching for the other reveal the answer? It really concerns the *3rd* movement, which is most un-moonlight-like!? While only the 1st movement is moonlight-ish.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. The other question does not relate to this one, and it's not a reasonable expectation that someone searching for this answer would read the comments — especially since there's no clear relationship between the questions.

Comment: @Aaron I disagree; all the necessary history is right there in a comment, and although the earlier question mentions a particular movement, it is the first hit when I search "moonlight sonata." I made an edit just now to its accepted answer to bring some of the data from the comment into an answer, but it's not expecting too much of people not only to search but to read the whole page (especially when the accepted answer mentions the comment, which was itself a comment because it simply pointed to Wikipedia).

Comment: @AndyBonner - with Aaron on this one. A  little technical, but fair nevertheless. And your edit happened *after*, not *before* the event.

Comment: (I guess the meta-question is, if there's a case where the question is distinct from an earlier one, but their answers are (essentially) the same, should they be handled separately?) At any rate, if we do re-open, let's give this one an answer that we'll be able to reference for any future "Why come the [X] Sonata is called [X]?" question.

Comment: @AndyBonner As a community, we tend to treat questions as duplicates, but not answers. Personally, I tend to agree with you that if the answers are duplicates, then the questions should be treated that way as well. However, in the case of this specific question, I think it's one that deserves its own dedicated post.

Comment: @AndyBonner - there are many occasions when the answer to different questions is the same, for all sorts of reasons. Simple example - the answer's 2, what's the question(s)?

Comment: @Tim “How many roads must a man walk down?”

Comment: @AndyBonner - sorry, that one doesn't fit the remit of this site..! Is the answer 'till he's found his satnav?'

Comment: The way duplicates work here is that they now both point to the same place, so any new person searching for **either** set of words will get to the right place.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - I don't see how asking the one question will come up with the answer to a different question, helping anyone. Why would someone trying to find out the name of someone type in '3rd movement, Moonlight'? And till now, the real answer was in a comment (till mine!).

Comment: It was in a comment under the duplicate question, yes (thankfully now edited into the top answer), but it was definitely visible there as soon as you went to that question.

Comment: Well done with enough editing the quoted question was made a dupe. Nothing like some after-the-fact editing to make a moderator choice correct.

Answer (score 1):

It was another Ludwig. This one was called Rellstab. Five years after Beethoven had died,(1832) he was the critic who named the 'Moonlight.

Comment: @Doktor Mayhem - that was in there to show what little effort was made by OP. I thought we preferred that questions showed at least some effort by OP.

Comment: Hi @Tim - yeah, we do, but it got flagged by a couple of folks as rude so thought I'd remove. It doesn't take away from your post.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - can't believe how sensitive some folks are... Must keep up the stocks of cotton wool ! A spade's a spade where I come from, but we're all different - it seems.